# GUI Unresponsive even while using threading and wxCallAfter and PubSub - Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a wxpython GUI - which calls a thread when a button is clicked. The target function of the thread contains serial communication, where I read data from an MCU and send back to the GUI using wx.CallAfter. My GUI is going unresponsive when the time.sleep function in my target function is 1 second. When I increased to 5 seconds, it is going unresponsive every 5 seconds or so.

THis is my target function

```
def ReadData(ser):

    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        try:
            #print "hello2"
            #print ("working on %s" % arg)
            data1 = Read(soa1, bytes1, ser)
            data2 = Read(soa2, bytes2, ser)
            data3 = Read(soa3, bytes3, ser)

            if (data1.size != 0) and (data2.size != 0) and (data3.size != 0):
                status_read = 1
                data = np.concatenate([data1, data2, data3])
                print data.size
            else:
                status_read = 0
        finally:
            lock.release()

        wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "READ EVENT", arg1=data, arg2=status_read)
        time.sleep(1)
```

The button event in my main GUI thread is as follows: This piece of code get executed after a button is pressed and the idea is to have it executed continuously

```
# Continuous Read  - Every 1 SECOND
        self.tr = threading.Thread(target=ReadData, name = "ReadThread", args=(self.ser,))
        self.tr.daemon = True
        self.tr.start()
        #time.sleep(0.2) # Just to be sure
        pub.subscribe(self.ReadEvent, "READ EVENT")
```

and my self.ser is with baudrate of 115200 and timeout of 3 seconds. Does anyone know why my GUI is behaving this way. To my knowledge it is not supposed to go unresponsive.  My self.ReadEvent is a function where I display the data on my GUI.